# ¿Como capturar el nombre de un usuario?

Tags: php

Estoy practicando php, estoy haciendo un registro de información de usuario. Ya guarda la información de logueo, pero el usuario es el email, y quiero que al momento de ingresar muestre el nombre del usuario que se esta logueando.

Tienen alguna idea de como hacerlo? 
    $link = mysqli_connect ($server, $user, $password, $db);

```
session_start();

$usuario = $_POST['email'];
$clave = $_POST['password'];

$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = '$usuario' and psw = '$clave' and usert = 'homestay'";

$consulta = mysqli_query($link,$q);

$array = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

if($array>0){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $usuario;
    header("location: homestay/index.php");
}else{
    echo "datos incorrectos";
}
```

Coloco este código debido a que no se en que parte del sistema se añade lo que quiero. Por lo que he investigado se debe almacenar todos los datos en variables de sesión, pero lo que no entiendo es si estoy haciendo el SELECT *, como hago para extraer de esa solicitud la fila del nombre y almacenarla en una variable para que al momento de ingresar diga "Bienvenido $nombre". He intentado encerrarlo en un array y solicitarlo por fila, pero no comprendo muy bien como hacerlo.

Cabe acotar que el nombre el usuario solo lo ingresa al momento de registrarse, no de inicio de sesión, quiero traer el nombre de la base de datos

Comment: Acá hay un error: `$_SESSION['username'] = $usuario;`, primero debes declarar la variable y luego asignar el valor usando las variables de sesión: `$nombreUsuario = $_SESSION['username'];`. Luego haces `echo $nombreUsuario;` para que se muestre en pantalla... Otro error es que estás sobre escribiendo el valor de `$usuario`, es mejor usar una variable diferente.

Comment: @DjCrazy la variable está definida en la 2da línea de código. Kleyber ¿cuál es el error o problema que tienes? Tu pregunta no está completa, pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla. Y pon el contexto completo, por ejemplo, ¿dónde incluyes la conexión (`$link`)?

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($array);` para visualizar que trae de información de tu consulta.

Comment: `$link = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena) or die("No se ha podido conectar con el servidor");` haz un `echo $link` para que veas si no esta mal desde tu conexión.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código te puede servir para hacer tus declaraciones de variables de sesión, adaptalo a tu consulta  yo estoy usando PDO .

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['conectado']="si";

$_SESSION['USUARIO']=$resultado[$i]->getCadenaApellido1()." ".$resultado[$i]->getCadenaApellido2()." ".$resultado[$i]->getCadenaNombre();
```

Esto yo lo tengo en un archivo para crear las sesiones que requiero solo estan de ejemplo 2, puede haber muchas mas.

Si deseas aumentar la seguridad de tu sistema y que si no hay una variable de sesion abierta te envie al login las siguientes lineas haran este trabajo

```html
<?php
        include_once "master/html/html_cabecera_menu_inc.php"; //Carga cabecera HTML, imagenes y algunos otros "adornos".
?>
<?php 
    /* inicio de la sesion */
    session_start(); 
   /* Si no hay una sesion creada,se redirecciona al index */
    if(empty($_SESSION['USUARIO'])) 
     { header("Location:login.php");}
?>
```

Si se intenta copear o pegar la ruta del archivo donde incluyas esta linea, y no hay sesion abierta, regresa al login.